# Page transition not smooth in android

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, html, css

I'm building a hybrid app using HTML5 and AngularJS. I'm using Angular animate for page transitions. The issue is that the transition is smooth in iOS devices, but there is a lag in android devices(Checked in Note5). Used translate3d for GPU acceleration. But still there is this issue. Is there any other way to make the animation smoother?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Plugins: https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/NativePageTransitions

Documentation: http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/native-page-transitions